# A Facebook script/extension that aids in deleting multiple "least interacted" friends at once

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm suffering from the repercussions of my past habit, and now I have tons of useless friends on my Facebook account.

There seems to exist no feature at the moment that entertains "multiple deletion" of friends, so as of now, I am at ends on how to "clean" my Facebook account.

Somehow, I was able to arrive at this script provided by Arjun Sreedharan, a [Facebook Friends Ranking Score](http://arjunsreedharan.org/post/65979958297/find-your-facebook-friends-ranking-score) list, that seems to generate a list of your **most interacted** friends (or any entity, it even includes pages and groups) with a respective "score".

I am not sure if this is quite legit, but so far from my use, it seems to match with friends I regularly interact in Facebook.

The problem you see, is it only gives a **LIMITED** list, about 200 of them with scores, and I have about 3,000 friends. I want to possibly procure all the scores, or more efficiently, get the **list of bottom 1,000 or 2,000 friends I least interact**, to which this new script also, possibly aids in "multiple deletion".

I don't care what implementation this "easy multiple deletion" will be, it may be:

- a list of links of the bottom 1,000/2,000 friends
- or the script opens 10 new tabs for every 10 friends in that list
- or any other ideas . . .

I'm not even asking for an automation, what I care is as long as it aids in an **easy** deletion of friends.

**PS. I'm not asking for a whole code, I just want to gain insights, aid, and tips on how to possibly do it. I am experienced in JavaScript (let's opt for this beause this is used in the aforementioned ranking score script above) but is at loss at any outsource scripting or Facebook scripting/extension knowledge. Any help or knowledge is appreciated.**

Comment: since this is scraping and there is no API to delete friends, this would most likely not be allowed...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about scraping Facebook pages, resp. doing things that are not officially supported.